# Proof rank of a special matrix is $n$ or $n - 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I am trying to do the following exercise:

> Let $m\in \mathbb N \backslash\{1,2\}$ and $A=(a_{ij})\in M_n(\mathbb Z)$ with $a_{ii} = 0$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$ and $a_{ij} = 1$ or $a_{ij} = m$ for all $1\leq i\neq j \leq n$. Show that $\text{rk } A = n -1$ or $\text{rk } A = n$.

Proof attempt:
Define $C:= A - B$, where $B\in M_n(\mathbb Z)$ with $b_{ij} = 1$ for all $1\leq i,j \leq n$. We then have $\det(C \mod (m-1)) = (-1)^n \neq 0 \implies \det C \neq 0$, hence $\text{rk } C = n$. I feel like I am close but don't know what's the final step. I could use $\text{rk } A = \text{rk } (C + B) \leq \text{rk }C + \text{rk }B = n$ but that is obvious in the first place. I too know that $\text{rk }A = n \Leftrightarrow A$ invertible $\Leftrightarrow \det A \in \{-1,1\}$ since $A$ has only entries from $\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:
$$
n = \text{rk }(C) = \text{rk } (A + (-B)) \leq \text{rk}A + \text{rk }B = 
\text{rk}(A) + 1
$$
Thus, conclude $\text{rk}(A) \geq n-1$.

Comment: Note: it is **not** true that $\text{rk }A = n \iff \det(A) \in \{\pm 1\}$.

Comment: It is, but only for $A\in GL_n(\mathbb Z)$. It is obvious for me now, I made the mistake of thinking $\text{rk } B = 0$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular_matrix

Comment: @lappen68 a matrix $A$ can have integer entries and rank $n$ without being an element of $GL_n(\Bbb Z)$.  The strong connection between rank and invertibility is lost when we take matrix entries from a ring rather than a field.

Comment: That is good to know, big mistake of mine. Thanks!

Comment: However it is still true that $\det A \neq 0 \Longleftrightarrow A$ invertible when we take entries from $\mathbb Z$, is it?

Comment: That depends what you mean by "invertible".  If you mean "$A$ has an inverse with rational/real entries", then yes.  If you mean "$A$ has an inverse with integer entries", then no.

Comment: I see, only the direction $A$ has an Inverse with arbitrary entries $\implies \det A = 0$ always holds, right? Thanks a lot btw!

Comment: If $A$ has an inverse of any kind, then $\det(A) \neq 0$.